# Selenium excel read and write to find row number

Tags: excel

In my program I want to find the row number in the excel sheet matching the string I have passed as argument . It works fine for first and second row but problem is with the next rows. My code to find row number  is as below :

```
    public int findrownum(String sName, String value, int cNum) throws Exception{
        File excel = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(sName);
        boolean check = true;
        int i=0;
        while (check){
            XSSFRow rowH = ws.getRow(i);
            XSSFCell cell = rowH.getCell(cNum);
            String cellvalue = cellToString(cell);
            if (cellvalue.equals(value)){
                check = false;
            }
            else {
                i = i+1;
            }
        }       

        return i;
    }

}
```

I want to read third row that is the string with name registration from the excel

Sl No   test case name  result  timestamp
1   login   Pass    03/03/2014 12:11:43 PM
2   Registration

Please let me know what changes needs to be done in the code .

Thanks

I used the similar logic as mentioned by @eric in JUNIT now i am able to find the row number .But now its giving error while i try to read the data using this row number . My code to read data is as below . Please let me know what changes needs to be done                                                                 public String dataread(String sName, int rNum, String cName) throws Exception{
        File excel = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(sName);
        XSSFRow rowH = ws.getRow(rNum-1);
        int totalRows = ws.getLastRowNum();

```
    int i =0;
    for(i=0;i<=totalRows;i++)

    {
        XSSFCell cell = rowH.getCell(i);
        String value = cellToString(cell);
        if (value.equals(cName)){
             System.out.println(i);
             break;
        }

    }
    XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(rNum);
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
    String value = cellToString(cell)          return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general [From this Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html) you can use the getHeight() to get in which your cursor instead of writing up your own loop.  Obviously this would reduce the execution time as well. Also the code which you have written could have caused the exception,as there is no more physical rows.

```
ws.getRow(i); can cause a fatal error if i>height of the last row
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code helps. The assumption is the data in the cell is string data. Also this is with apache poi api.

```
public static String getcellValue(int testRowNo, int colNo)
    {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String excelPath = projectPath + "/TestSet.xlsx";
        File excel = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Workbook workBook = null;
        String cellValue = null;
        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
            workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet workSheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
            int totalRows = workSheet.getLastRowNum();
            Row row = null;
            cellValue  = workSheet.getRow(testRowNo).getCell(colNo).getStringCellValue();


        } catch (InvalidFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            try
            {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return cellValue;
    }

public static int getrowNumber(String sheetName, String cellData)
    {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String excelPath = projectPath + "/TestSet.xlsx";
        File excel = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Workbook workBook = null;
        String cellValue = null;
        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
            workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet workSheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
            int totalRows = workSheet.getLastRowNum();
            Row row = null;
            int testRowNo = 0;
            for(int rowNo =1; rowNo<=totalRows; rowNo++)
            {
                row = workSheet.getRow(rowNo);
                testRowNo = testRowNo +1;
                if(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(cellData))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


        } catch (InvalidFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            try
            {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return testRowNo;
    }
```

Comment: I used the similar logic in JUNIT now i am able to find the row number .But now its giving error while i try to read the data using this row number . My code to read data is as below . Please let me know what changes needs to be done

Comment: Did you use the method i have posted? This will return the row number and you can use it and probably create another method which takes the row and column number as argument and reads data from the cell.

Comment: Yes I have used the same method . Can you let me know the method to read the data using this row number . The logic I am using is not working .